"AJAX Request Not Working: Listener Indicated Asynchronous Response but Message Channel Closed" Unsure where to go from here
I'm working on a simple search functionality using jQuery and AJAX. The script is supposed to send a POST request whenever the user types in the search box and display the results in a div below the search box. However, I'm encountering issues with the input event not being triggered, the console only displays the message Document is ready. For further context, the database is an sqlite3 database.
Here’s my current code:
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Document is ready."); // Check if the document ready function is triggered

    var searchBox = $("#search-box");
    console.log("Search box element:", searchBox); // Log the search box element

    searchBox.on("input", function() {
        console.log("Input event triggered."); // Check if the input event is triggered
        
        var searchboxValue = $(this).val();
        console.log("Search box value:", searchboxValue); // Log the value of the search box
        
        var resultDiv = $(this).next(".result");
        console.log("Result div:", resultDiv); // Log the result div
        
        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: "/",
            data: { text: searchboxValue },
            success: function(res) {
                console.log("AJAX success:", res); // Log the successful response
                
                var data = "<ul>";
                $.each(res, function(index, value) {
                    data += "<li>" + value.player_name + " - " + value.picture_path + "</li>";
                });
                data += "</ul>";
                resultDiv.html(data).show();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error("AJAX error:", status, error); // Log any errors
            }
        });
    });
});

The HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fantasy Basketball Trade Analyzer</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Fantasy Basketball Trade Analyzer</h1>
        <div class="trade-container">
            <div class="left-side">
                <div class="search-container">
                    <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Player Name" id="player1-left">
                    <div class="result" id="result1-left"></div>
                    <p class="instruction">Start typing to select a player...</p>
                    <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Player Two" id="player2-left">
                    <div class="result" id="result2-left"></div>
                    <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Player Three" id="player3-left">
                    <div class="result" id="result3-left"></div>
                    <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Player Four" id="player4-left">
                    <div class="result" id="result4-left"></div>
                    <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Player Five" id="player5-left">
                    <div class="result" id="result5-left"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side">
                <div class="search-container">
                    <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Player Name" id="player1-right">
                    <div class="result" id="result1-right"></div>
                    <p class="instruction">Start typing to select a player...</p>
                    <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Player Two" id="player2-right">
                    <div class="result" id="result2-right"></div>
                    <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Player Three" id="player3-right">
                    <div class="result" id="result3-right"></div>
                    <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Player Four" id="player4-right">
                    <div class="result" id="result4-right"></div>
                    <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Player Five" id="player5-right">
                    <div class="result" id="result5-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="analyze-button">
            <img src="https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/fantasy/fba.png&w=288&h=288&transparent=true" alt="NBA logo">
            ANALYZE TRADE
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

I essentially ran the code, my front page loads, up as intended, but clicking any one of the searchboxes and typing yields nothing. Text just appears in the box. Checking the console before and after typing in the box shows no difference, the "Document is ready" message I prepared loads up as expected. What is supposed to happen is typing in the box releases a list of boxes below of names similar to the ones being typed.

Do you not see the console.log("Search box element:", searchBox) message logged?

This looks like a simple typo. You have no element with id="search-box" to match your #search-box selector
